# Python array sort

Tags: python

From a CTF challenge, a easy pwn(elf). I could probably have done it in better way, but anyway I ended up with the flag in a array looking like this.

```
['4:a', '27:a', '33:a', '39:b', '5:c', '31:c', '44:c', '45:c', '18:d', '37:d', '2:e', '21:e', '25:e', '29:e', '36:e', '46:e', '35:g', '3:h','32:h', '17:i', '6:k', '10:l', '24:l', '9:n', '34:n', '22:o', '16:p', '20:p', '23:p', '28:r', '13:s', '42:s', '47:s', '48:s', '14:t', '15:u','43:u', '1:w', '11:y', '40:y', '8:O', '7:{', '49:}', '12:_', '19:_', '26:_', '30:_', '38:_', '41:_','0:$']
```

Is it possible to sort this array in easy way?

Comment: It's easy to sort using [Python sort function](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-function-python/).  What criteria do you want to use in sorting?  If you just want each item treated as a string and sorted in alphabetical order than sorted(your-array) will do that.  Also: your.array.sort() to sort in-place.

Comment: The first char in the flag is 0:$ the second is 1:w, so I want to sort it by the numbers

Comment: @r4113 You may accept the answer, if it solves your problem. If not, feel free to ask any question.

Answer (score 4):

````
flagArray = ['4:a', '27:a', '33:a', '39:b', '5:c', '31:c', '44:c', '45:c', '18:d', '37:d', '2:e', '21:e', '25:e', '29:e', '36:e', '46:e', '35:g', '3:h','32:h', '17:i', '6:k', '10:l', '24:l', '9:n', '34:n', '22:o', '16:p', '20:p', '23:p', '28:r', '13:s', '42:s', '47:s', '48:s', '14:t', '15:u','43:u', '1:w', '11:y', '40:y', '8:O', '7:{', '49:}', '12:_', '19:_', '26:_', '30:_', '38:_', '41:_','0:$']```

def getNumber(x):
  return int(x.split(":")[0])

sorted(flagArray, key = getNumber)

>>>
['0:$',
 '1:w',
 '2:e',
 '3:h',
 '4:a',
 '5:c',
 '6:k',
 '7:{',
 '8:O',
 '9:n',
 '10:l',
 '11:y',
 '12:_',
 '13:s',
 '14:t',
 '15:u',
 '16:p',
 '17:i',
 '18:d',
 '19:_',
 '20:p',
 '21:e',
 '22:o',
 '23:p',
 '24:l',
 '25:e',
 '26:_',
 '27:a',
 '28:r',
 '29:e',
 '30:_',
 '31:c',
 '32:h',
 '33:a',
 '34:n',
 '35:g',
 '36:e',
 '37:d',
 '38:_',
 '39:b',
 '40:y',
 '41:_',
 '42:s',
 '43:u',
 '44:c',
 '45:c',
 '46:e',
 '47:s',
 '48:s',
 '49:}']
````

The array will be sorted by the number part of each element

**A oneliner approach would be to use a lambda function**

```
sorted(flagArray, key = lambda x : int(x.split(":")[0]))
```

Answer (score 2):

## One liner solution

You can use inbuilt python functions `sort` or `sorted` along with `lambda` function.

```
my_list = ['4:a', '27:a', '33:a', '39:b', '5:c', '31:c', '44:c', '45:c', '18:d', '37:d', '2:e', '21:e', '25:e', '29:e', '36:e', '46:e', '35:g', '3:h','32:h', '17:i', '6:k', '10:l', '24:l', '9:n', '34:n', '22:o', '16:p', '20:p', '23:p', '28:r', '13:s', '42:s', '47:s', '48:s', '14:t', '15:u','43:u', '1:w', '11:y', '40:y', '8:O', '7:{', '49:}', '12:_', '19:_', '26:_', '30:_', '38:_', '41:_','0:$']
```

**Inplace Sort**

```
my_list.sort(key=lambda k: k.split(':')[0])
```

**Getting sorted list as a copy**

```
sorted_list = sorted(a, key=lambda k: k.split(':')[0])
```